# Extract element in sublist using other sublist

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I have 2 nested arrays

```
Test = [['c','d','b','t','j','n','k','s','p','t','k'],['l','u','y','r','c','b']]

Sample = [[1,0,1,1,2,0,3,4,0,0,4],[1,0,1,2,0,3]]
```

I want output like whenever 0 in Sample array.I want to extract corresponding letter in Test array.Both array lengths are same

```
Output = [['d','n','p','t],['u','c']]
```

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? If you don't know what a for loop is, I suggest you start by reading about it

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Test = [['c','d','b','t','j','n','k','s','p','t','k'],['l','u','y','r','c','b']]
Sample = [[1,0,1,1,2,0,3,4,0,0,4],[1,0,1,2,0,3]]

final_list = []
for j in range(len(Test)):
  sub_list = []
  for i in range(len(Test[j])):
    if Sample[j][i] == 0:
      sub_list.append(Test[j][i])
  final_list.append(sub_list)
```

Where final_list is your expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
res = [list(np.array(a)[np.array(b) == 0]) for a,b in zip(Test, Sample)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a job for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [
    [t for t, s in zip(test, sample) if s == 0]
    for test, sample in zip(Test, Sample)
]
```

Result:

```
[['d', 'n', 'p', 't'], ['u', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop and `zip()` does all the work

```
final_list = []

for x,y in zip(Test, Sample):
    _list=[]                   # Temp. list to append to

    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        if j == 0:
                _list.append(i)
    final_list.append(_list)   # appending to final list to create list of list
    del _list                  # del. the temp_list to avoid duplicate values
    
final_list
```